# CSS3: Text stay in the box when translated

Tags: css, translate

I've make a slide presentation in CSS3/javascript but this don't work properly..

When you click on the arrow the "diapos" div are moving on a direction but  in my case the text inside the boxes are not totally moving and a small portion of text stay in the the next slide

```js
function clic_left() {
          var objet = document.getElementById("diapo1");
           left = getComputedStyle(objet, null).left;
           var left2 = parseInt(left);
           left2=left2+2000;  
           diapo1.style.left=left2+"px";
           
           var objet = document.getElementById("diapo2");
           left = getComputedStyle(objet, null).left;
           var left2 = parseInt(left);
           left2=left2+2000;
           diapo2.style.left=left2+"px";
           
           var objet = document.getElementById("diapo3");
           left = getComputedStyle(objet, null).left;
           var left2 = parseInt(left);
           left2=left2+2000;
           diapo3.style.left=left2+"px";
}

function clic_right() {
          var objet = document.getElementById("diapo1");
           left = getComputedStyle(objet, null).left;
           var left2 = parseInt(left);
           left2=left2-2000;  
           diapo1.style.left=left2+"px";
           
           var objet = document.getElementById("diapo2");
           left = getComputedStyle(objet, null).left;
           var left2 = parseInt(left);
           left2=left2-2000;
           diapo2.style.left=left2+"px";
           
            var objet = document.getElementById("diapo3");
           left = getComputedStyle(objet, null).left;
           var left2 = parseInt(left);
           left2=left2-2000;
           diapo3.style.left=left2+"px";
}
```

```css
#arrow_left {
color: red;
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
bottom: 50%;
left: 5%;
opacity: 0.3;

}

#arrow_right {
color: red;
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
bottom: 50%;
right: 5%;
opacity: 0.3;
}

#arrow_right:hover {
displa      y: block;
opacity: 1;

transform: translate(5px);
cursor: pointer;

}


#arrow_left:hover {
display: block;
opacity: 1;
transform: translate(-5px);
cursor: pointer;
}

.bordure_left  {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 10%;
 height: 1024;
    top: 3em;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
 z-index: 9;
}

.bordure_right {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 10%;
 height: 1024;
    top: 3em;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
 z-index: 9;
}

.centre {
 position: absolute;
    height: 100em;
 width: 1020px;
    margin: 118px;
    margin-top: 3em;
 border: 5px solid;
 z-index: 1;

}

#diapo1 {
 position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
 z-index: 1;
    transition: 1s;
}

#diapo2 {
 position: absolute;
    left: 2000px;
 z-index: 1;
    transition: 1s;
}

#diapo3 {
 position: absolute;
    left: 4000px;
 z-index: 1;
    transition: 1s;
}

.robot {
    text-align: center;
    white-space: normal;
    text-shadow: 1px 2px grey;
 color: black;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 font-family: SaborDigital;
 word-spacing: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Projet SIN</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel=stylesheet type="text/css" />
 <script src="js/slide.js"></script>
</head>

<body scroll="no" style="overflow: hidden"> <!-- no scroll -->
    <div class="bordure_left">
  <p id="arrow_left" onclick="clic_left()">ARROW<p> 
    </div>
    
    <div class="bordure_right">
    <p id="arrow_right" onclick="clic_right()">ARROW<p> 
    </div>
     
    <div class="centre">
 <div id="diapo1">
 
    <p class="robot">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam fermentum sagittis sagittis. Duis dui magna, pellentesque sed efficitur nec, maximus vitae ligula. Nunc sed diam interdum, dapibus erat et, sollicitudin leo. Sed egestas dui eget placerat vestibulum. Quisque ac egestas est. Praesent vel augue vitae sapien consectetur maximus eu eget massa. Quisque dictum libero vel nulla venenatis, eget varius nisl pulvinar. Fusce cursus dapibus sem a efficitur. Quisque vel mauris at nunc malesuada tincidunt. Nam maximus augue augue, eu hendrerit libero vulputate eu. Nulla convallis nibh leo, ut pretium ipsum condimentum sit amet. Proin porttitor orci est, in posuere augue euismod vitae. 
    </p>
    
        <p class="robot">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam fermentum sagittis sagittis. Duis dui magna, pellentesque sed efficitur nec, maximus vitae ligula. Nunc sed diam interdum, dapibus erat et, sollicitudin leo. Sed egestas dui eget placerat vestibulum. Quisque ac egestas est. Praesent vel augue vitae sapien consectetur maximus eu eget massa. Quisque dictum libero vel nulla venenatis, eget varius nisl pulvinar. Fusce cursus dapibus sem a efficitur. Quisque vel mauris at nunc malesuada tincidunt. Nam maximus augue augue, eu hendrerit libero vulputate eu. Nulla convallis nibh leo, ut pretium ipsum condimentum sit amet. Proin porttitor orci est, in posuere augue euismod vitae. 
    </p>
    
    
    

    
 </div>
 
    <div id="diapo2">
 
    <p class="robot">AAA  ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam fermentum sagittis sagittis. Duis dui magna, pellentesque sed efficitur nec, maximus vitae ligula. Nunc sed diam interdum, dapibus erat et, sollicitudin leo. Sed egestas dui eget placerat vestibulum. Quisque ac egestas est. Praesent vel augue vitae sapien consectetur maximus eu eget massa. Quisque dictum libero vel nulla venenatis, eget varius nisl pulvinar. Fusce cursus dapibus sem a efficitur. Quisque vel mauris at nunc malesuada tincidunt. Nam maximus augue augue, eu hendrerit libero vulputate eu. Nulla convallis nibh leo, ut pretium ipsum condimentum sit amet. Proin porttitor orci est, in posuere augue euismod vitae. 
    </p>
    
        <p class="robot">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam fermentum sagittis sagittis. Duis dui magna, pellentesque sed efficitur nec, maximus vitae ligula. Nunc sed diam interdum, dapibus erat et, sollicitudin leo. Sed egestas dui eget placerat vestibulum. Quisque ac egestas est. Praesent vel augue vitae sapien consectetur maximus eu eget massa. Quisque dictum libero vel nulla venenatis, eget varius nisl pulvinar. Fusce cursus dapibus sem a efficitur. Quisque vel mauris at nunc malesuada tincidunt. Nam maximus augue augue, eu hendrerit libero vulputate eu. Nulla convallis nibh leo, ut pretium ipsum condimentum sit amet. Proin porttitor orci est, in posuere augue euismod vitae. 
    </p>
    

    
 </div>
 
    <div id="diapo3">
 
    <p class="robot">AAA  ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam fermentum sagittis sagittis. Duis dui magna, pellentesque sed efficitur nec, maximus vitae ligula. Nunc sed diam interdum, dapibus erat et, sollicitudin leo. Sed egestas dui eget placerat vestibulum. Quisque ac egestas est. Praesent vel augue vitae sapien consectetur maximus eu eget massa. Quisque dictum libero vel nulla venenatis, eget varius nisl pulvinar. Fusce cursus dapibus sem a efficitur. Quisque vel mauris at nunc malesuada tincidunt. Nam maximus augue augue, eu hendrerit libero vulputate eu. Nulla convallis nibh leo, ut pretium ipsum condimentum sit amet. Proin porttitor orci est, in posuere augue euismod vitae. 
    </p>
    
        <p class="robot">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam fermentum sagittis sagittis. Duis dui magna, pellentesque sed efficitur nec, maximus vitae ligula. Nunc sed diam interdum, dapibus erat et, sollicitudin leo. Sed egestas dui eget placerat vestibulum. Quisque ac egestas est. Praesent vel augue vitae sapien consectetur maximus eu eget massa. Quisque dictum libero vel nulla venenatis, eget varius nisl pulvinar. Fusce cursus dapibus sem a efficitur. Quisque vel mauris at nunc malesuada tincidunt. Nam maximus augue augue, eu hendrerit libero vulputate eu. Nulla convallis nibh leo, ut pretium ipsum condimentum sit amet. Proin porttitor orci est, in posuere augue euismod vitae. 
    </p>
    

    
 </div>
 
 
    </div>
</body>
```

click on the "arrow" button to make the translation

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you strictly need to build this from scratch or are you able/have considered using a Carousel plugin or similar components?

Comment: I'm doing this for a school project so i want to build everything from scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing fine, just remember that `position` and `display` are tricky CSS options that you need to master by trying out and understanding what they do.

Your example was missing some `width` and `height` on the `#diapo*` elements. The `p` started to fill in the blanks of the missing space.

I added some `background-color`, so you can debug it more easily.

**References:**
https://zellwk.com/blog/css-positions/ and 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

```js
function clic_left() {
  var objet = document.getElementById("diapo1");
  left = getComputedStyle(objet, null).left;
  var left2 = parseInt(left);
  left2 = left2 + 2000;
  diapo1.style.left = left2 + "px";

  var objet = document.getElementById("diapo2");
  left = getComputedStyle(objet, null).left;
  var left2 = parseInt(left);
  left2 = left2 + 2000;
  diapo2.style.left = left2 + "px";

  var objet = document.getElementById("diapo3");
  left = getComputedStyle(objet, null).left;
  var left2 = parseInt(left);
  left2 = left2 + 2000;
  diapo3.style.left = left2 + "px";
}

function clic_right() {
  var objet = document.getElementById("diapo1");
  left = getComputedStyle(objet, null).left;
  var left2 = parseInt(left);
  left2 = left2 - 2000;
  diapo1.style.left = left2 + "px";

  var objet = document.getElementById("diapo2");
  left = getComputedStyle(objet, null).left;
  var left2 = parseInt(left);
  left2 = left2 - 2000;
  diapo2.style.left = left2 + "px";

  var objet = document.getElementById("diapo3");
  left = getComputedStyle(objet, null).left;
  var left2 = parseInt(left);
  left2 = left2 - 2000;
  diapo3.style.left = left2 + "px";
}
```

```css
#arrow_left {
  color: red;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 5%;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

#arrow_right {
  color: red;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  right: 5%;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

#arrow_right:hover {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(5px);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#arrow_left:hover {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-5px);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bordure_left {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  height: 1024;
  top: 3em;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 9;
}

.bordure_right {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  height: 1024;
  top: 3em;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 9;
}

.centre {
  position: relative; /* changed */
  height: 100em;
  width: 1020px;
  margin: 118px;
  margin-top: 3em;
  border: 5px solid;
  z-index: 1;
}

#diapo1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 1s;
  background: red;
  height: 100%; /* changed */
  width: 100%; /* changed */
}

#diapo2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2000px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 1s;
  background: blue;
  height: 100%; /* changed */
  width: 100%; /* changed */
}

#diapo3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 4000px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 1s;
  background: green;
  height: 100%; /* changed */
  width: 100%; /* changed */
}

.robot {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: normal;
  text-shadow: 1px 2px grey;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: SaborDigital;
  word-spacing: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Projet SIN</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel=stylesheet type="text/css" />
  <script src="js/slide.js"></script>
</head>

<body scroll="no" style="overflow: hidden">
  <!-- no scroll -->
  <div class="bordure_left">
    <p id="arrow_left" onclick="clic_left()">ARROW
      <p>
  </div>

  <div class="bordure_right">
    <p id="arrow_right" onclick="clic_right()">ARROW
      <p>
  </div>

  <div class="centre">
    <div id="diapo1">

      <p class="robot">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam fermentum sagittis sagittis. Duis dui magna, pellentesque sed efficitur nec, maximus vitae ligula. Nunc sed diam interdum, dapibus erat et, sollicitudin leo. Sed egestas dui eget placerat
        vestibulum. Quisque ac egestas est. Praesent vel augue vitae sapien consectetur maximus eu eget massa. Quisque dictum libero vel nulla venenatis, eget varius nisl pulvinar. Fusce cursus dapibus sem a efficitur. Quisque vel mauris at nunc malesuada
        tincidunt. Nam maximus augue augue, eu hendrerit libero vulputate eu. Nulla convallis nibh leo, ut pretium ipsum condimentum sit amet. Proin porttitor orci est, in posuere augue euismod vitae.
      </p>

      <p class="robot">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam fermentum sagittis sagittis. Duis dui magna, pellentesque sed efficitur nec, maximus vitae ligula. Nunc sed diam interdum, dapibus erat et, sollicitudin leo. Sed egestas dui eget placerat
        vestibulum. Quisque ac egestas est. Praesent vel augue vitae sapien consectetur maximus eu eget massa. Quisque dictum libero vel nulla venenatis, eget varius nisl pulvinar. Fusce cursus dapibus sem a efficitur. Quisque vel mauris at nunc malesuada
        tincidunt. Nam maximus augue augue, eu hendrerit libero vulputate eu. Nulla convallis nibh leo, ut pretium ipsum condimentum sit amet. Proin porttitor orci est, in posuere augue euismod vitae.
      </p>





    </div>

    <div id="diapo2">

      <p class="robot">AAA ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam fermentum sagittis sagittis. Duis dui magna, pellentesque sed efficitur nec, maximus vitae ligula. Nunc sed diam interdum, dapibus erat et, sollicitudin leo. Sed egestas dui eget placerat
        vestibulum. Quisque ac egestas est. Praesent vel augue vitae sapien consectetur maximus eu eget massa. Quisque dictum libero vel nulla venenatis, eget varius nisl pulvinar. Fusce cursus dapibus sem a efficitur. Quisque vel mauris at nunc malesuada
        tincidunt. Nam maximus augue augue, eu hendrerit libero vulputate eu. Nulla convallis nibh leo, ut pretium ipsum condimentum sit amet. Proin porttitor orci est, in posuere augue euismod vitae.
      </p>

      <p class="robot">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam fermentum sagittis sagittis. Duis dui magna, pellentesque sed efficitur nec, maximus vitae ligula. Nunc sed diam interdum, dapibus erat et, sollicitudin leo. Sed egestas dui eget placerat
        vestibulum. Quisque ac egestas est. Praesent vel augue vitae sapien consectetur maximus eu eget massa. Quisque dictum libero vel nulla venenatis, eget varius nisl pulvinar. Fusce cursus dapibus sem a efficitur. Quisque vel mauris at nunc malesuada
        tincidunt. Nam maximus augue augue, eu hendrerit libero vulputate eu. Nulla convallis nibh leo, ut pretium ipsum condimentum sit amet. Proin porttitor orci est, in posuere augue euismod vitae.
      </p>



    </div>

    <div id="diapo3">

      <p class="robot">AAA ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam fermentum sagittis sagittis. Duis dui magna, pellentesque sed efficitur nec, maximus vitae ligula. Nunc sed diam interdum, dapibus erat et, sollicitudin leo. Sed egestas dui eget placerat
        vestibulum. Quisque ac egestas est. Praesent vel augue vitae sapien consectetur maximus eu eget massa. Quisque dictum libero vel nulla venenatis, eget varius nisl pulvinar. Fusce cursus dapibus sem a efficitur. Quisque vel mauris at nunc malesuada
        tincidunt. Nam maximus augue augue, eu hendrerit libero vulputate eu. Nulla convallis nibh leo, ut pretium ipsum condimentum sit amet. Proin porttitor orci est, in posuere augue euismod vitae.
      </p>

      <p class="robot">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam fermentum sagittis sagittis. Duis dui magna, pellentesque sed efficitur nec, maximus vitae ligula. Nunc sed diam interdum, dapibus erat et, sollicitudin leo. Sed egestas dui eget placerat
        vestibulum. Quisque ac egestas est. Praesent vel augue vitae sapien consectetur maximus eu eget massa. Quisque dictum libero vel nulla venenatis, eget varius nisl pulvinar. Fusce cursus dapibus sem a efficitur. Quisque vel mauris at nunc malesuada
        tincidunt. Nam maximus augue augue, eu hendrerit libero vulputate eu. Nulla convallis nibh leo, ut pretium ipsum condimentum sit amet. Proin porttitor orci est, in posuere augue euismod vitae.
      </p>



    </div>


  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks ! I need to more understand position in css because this can be a bit disturbing in the beginning, it'll allow me to stop asking that kind of question.

Comment: Keep asking question, that's also a way to learn. CSS is hard. Good luck with your project.